# Mythweb is showing directory listing instead of mythweb homepage

Tags: apache2

This may have happened some time ago.

I have only noticed recently because I finally wanted to use myth-web to remove some unwanted TV channels.

When I try to access http://localhost/mythweb on the backend, I get a page labelled "Index of /mythweb" instead of the myth-web html page that I was expecting.

Also a similar result occurs when accessing it from another PC on the network.

I searched for an answer and found a few references to various fixes for a problem that was caused by a bug introduced last year. This bug was the incorrect location of some files etc.

I tried the things that they suggested to no avail.

Now I am stuck.

Is it possible just to remove myth-web and do a clean re-install, with a new set of configuration files?

Thanks in advance for your help.

David

Comment: This question is not really about Ubuntu and would do better at https://superuser.com/

Comment: @Minos: Mythweb is a standard part of [Mythbuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mythbuntu) which is in the [official Ubuntu releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) so **definitely on-topic here!  ;-)**

Comment: Solved the issue anyway but thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Fabby Sorry, my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh and the solution was ţo purge mythweb and reinstall using apt-get.